# Drools says order and product types are a mismatch

Tags: drools, rule-engine

I have an order which can be defined in 2 product categories separately. The order has a category which could be in the first product category or in another product sub-category. Either way, both products fully describe the order. The order is a type of produce and is also a fruit. Orders, fall into these situations as this is a legacy application.   However, when I write the drl file, it fails with an error that the types are a mismatch, both a string fields. The problem is that the products are disjoint, so it is difficult to match them and get the rules to fire. I want the condition to be satisfied by both products. If I attempt with one product there is a match but that picks several other products which I don't want in the list. The order must match the 2 conditions even though they are separate facts.

Here is my drl file:

```
 rule "check Order in Produce and type is fruit"

 when
    $order : Order( $orderId: orderId , $category: category  )
    $prod2 : Product( this.type == 'FRUIT', this.orderId == $orderId, 
                                          $name1: name)
   $prod3 : Product( this.type == "PRODUCE", this.name != $name1, 
    this.category == $category)
 then 
    System.out.println("Found a binding type "+$order) ;

end
```

My class files look like this, I have put the values of one product, omitting the other. I place the actual values of the first product.

```
class Product{
   String name;
   String type= "FRUIT";
   String orderId = "123";
  String category = "PRODUCE";

 }
```

The order class is shown below:

```
      class Order{
       String orderId;
       String category;
      }
```

I would be very grateful if someone could help, please

Comment: When you say "it fails with an error that the types are a mismatch", are you referring to an actual error in Drools or is it that the rule is not being fired? If you do get an error, could you please add the stacktrace of the error to this question?

Comment: Thanks it was my mistake, the import was not at the top for the object

Comment: Thank you’,  it was my mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The import was not included for the object; once I placed it it worked